# Door not closing properly unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a door in my unity game for testing purposes, but I'm finding that my door doesn't shut completely once it has been opened.

This is most of my code for my door

```
        {
            unlockedSound.Play();
            locked = false;
            keyOB.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(unlockDoor());
        }

        if (inReach && doorisClosed && unlocked && Input.GetButtonDown("Interact"))
        {
            door.SetBool("Open", true);
            door.SetBool("Closed", false);
            openText.SetActive(false);
            openSound.Play();
            doorisOpen = true;
            doorisClosed = false;
        }

        else if (inReach && doorisOpen && unlocked && Input.GetButtonDown("Interact"))
        {
            door.SetBool("Open", false);
            door.SetBool("Closed", true);
            closeText.SetActive(false);
            closeSound.Play();
            doorisOpen = false;
            doorisClosed = true;
        }


        if (inReach && locked && Input.GetButtonDown("Interact"))
        {
            openText.SetActive(false);
            lockedText.SetActive(true);
            lockedSound.Play();
        }

    }

    IEnumerator unlockDoor()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        {
            unlocked = true;
            lockOB.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

I have the animations set to properly close the door, I'm unsure of how to move forward with this.

I have even tried isolating the door and suspending it in the air incase something was preventing it from closing properly

Comment: Well, if the animation is ok, and no weird collider is blocking your door, maybe it's something with your animation bools or transitions? Try to debug it with animator open, so you know in which state you are at the moment and it can give you some insights.

Comment: I got rid of the transition time between doorOpen and doorClosed and it seemed to fix it, thanks! @bartol44